# Google Analytics: how to use specific events in dimension grouping?

Tags: google-analytics

How can I group by specific event values and exclude any other events?

I considered I could filter a custom report by the range of allowable event values, but I can't do this since 1) I seem to be an 8-filter limit and 2) I'm afraid the report would lose pageviews from users who don't see the report.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the Google Analytics Data Export API you can freely apply filters without any limitation and with the ability to use regular expressions: http://code.google.com/intl/en/apis/analytics/docs/gdata/gdataReferenceDataFeed.html#filters